# How create a file using the two variables?

Tags: string, batch-file, int

In .bat file I have two variables : `int` and `string`. For example : `5` and `"qwerty"`. I need to create file `"qwerty5.txt"`. How convert int to string ? And then add to first string ?

Comment: `cmd` does not differentiate between INT and STRING. Just use `set "filename=%string%%int%.txt"`

Comment: `cmd` stores all environment variables as strings, so they simply need to be concatenated. There are commands and structures that manipulate strings as though they were integers, but actually they are converted from a string to an integer, the calculation performed and the result returned as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
if not exist "%string%%int%.txt" (echo:>"%string%%int%.txt")
```